# how to query(search) of sql on Amazon Athena which has JSON value?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

[1st err while querying[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vObuD.png)

[image: Screenshot of the data of Athena:]

```
select * from table where properties 'year' = 2007 // is not working
//please check the screen shot of the table
```

I want to query on Athena dataset throug sql query. I tried every query but its not working on this Athena data

Comment: Use `json_extract`. See: [6.12. JSON Functions and Operators — Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)

Comment: its not working!

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you tried and what happened.

Comment: check the screen shot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the `properties` column is a `STRING`, in that case you can do this to extract the `year` field and use it in a filter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(properties, '$.year') = '2007'
```

Notice that it's `'2007'`, not `2007`, since from your screenshot it looks like the values are strings.

You can read more about the [`JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` function and other JSON manipulation functions in the documentation for the Presto version that Athena is currently using](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar).