# AWS Glue table Map data type for arbitratry number of fields and challenges faced

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We are working on a Data-Lake project and we are getting the data from the cloudwatch logs, which in turn is going to be sent to S3 through the help of Kinesis service. Once this is in S3, we need to create a table to see the data through Athena, we have JSON files. We have 3 fields one is timestamp and the other one is properties, which in turn is an object which may hold arbitrary number of fields and differs on case to case, hence while creating the table, I defined it to be `map<string,string>`, based on some research and advises. Now the challenge is while querying through Athena, it always says zero records returned when there is data for sure. To confirm this, I have create a table this time through crawler and I am able to see the data through Athena, but only difference is the properties column is defined as struct with specific fields inside it, but where manual table has `map<string,string>` to handle arbitrary fileds coming in. Appreciate for any help to identify the root cause against this. Thank you.

Below is sample JSON line which is sitting in S3.

```
{"streamedAt":1599012411567,"properties":{"timestamp":1597998038615,"message":"Example Event 1","processFlag":"true"},"event":"aws:kinesis:record"}
```

Comment: try creating a table with crawler which has arbitrary information in the column and see if you are able to fetch the information via Athena?

Comment: @Manjunath did you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero records returned usually means the table's location is wrong, or that you have a partitioned table but haven't added any partitions. I assume you would have figured it out if it was the former, so I suspect the latter. When you run a crawler it will add partitions it finds in addition to creating the table.

If you need help adding partitions please edit your question and provide examples of how your data is structured on S3.

This is a case where using a Glue crawler will probably not work very well, it will try too hard to figure out the schema of the `properties` column and it's never going to get it right. Glue crawlers are in general pretty bad at things that aren't very basic (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297671/querying-optional-nested-json-fields-in-athena) for a similar use case to yours when Glue didn't work out).

I think you'll be fine with a manually created table that uses `map<string,string>` as the type for the `properties` column. When you know the type of a property and want to use it as that type you just cast the value at query time. An alternative is to use `string` as the type and use the [JSON functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) to extract values at query time.